# Reading German Church Records

Tags: germany, birth-records, marriage-records, kurrent

These are fairly easy to read, but there are a few words that I can't read.

The godparents/witnesses usually aren't that useful, I am less concerned about them.

The mother's surname is spelled two ways, Holst or Holz. Both seem to be valid names, although Holst is usually Scandinavian.

Lise is a nickname for Elisabeth?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, Lise is a variant of Elisabeth.

Comment: the name "Lise" originated from "Elisabeth", but it's a normal female name by itself, that is, if it is written in the church record then the woman's name is Lise and not Elisabeth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I got everything:

First image:
The occupation is "Weber" (weaver)

Second image:
The occupation is again "Weber". The bride part is "Jgf. Ann. Elis. Holz daselbst". "Jgf." means "Jungfrau" in the sense that she is unmarried. "daselbst" is "at the same place", so Mönchhagen.

Third image:
The occupation is "Schneider" (tailor).